# Where can I find the implementation of remainder operator in java?

Tags: java, math

I would like to find the exact implementation of the remainder operator (`%`) on `double`'s in java. Do you know where I can find it? (Sorry if this is obvious knowledge)

Comment: On OpenJDK, use -XX:+PrintAssembly to see the generated code (some setup is required -- search for it).  (On architectures with native floating-point remainder, it should just use that instruction; on architectures where floating-point is provided in software, it's probably a trap or library call.)

Comment: If you just want to know the precise details of how the operator works, the [Java Language Specification, section 15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact implementation of language features is in the JVM. It will probably depend on the CPU architecture the specific JVM version is designed and compiled for.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer isn't the answer, unforntunately. I've been trying to find out the same, and here is what I've found for the OpenJDK:

- [Zlib implementation mod()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/util/zip/zlib-1.2.3/zadler32.c#L47) (zipping library)
- [BigInteger mod()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L1376)

There are also some modulus/o operations in various security classes.

According to the [Java 8 StrictMath docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html),

> The Java math library is defined with respect to fdlibm version [5.3](http://www.validlab.com/software/).
>   Where fdlibm provides more than one definition for a function (such as
>   acos), use the "IEEE 754 core function" version (residing in a file
>   whose name begins with the letter e). The methods which require fdlibm
>   semantics are sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan, exp, log, log10, cbrt,
>   atan2, pow, sinh, cosh, tanh, hypot, expm1, and log1p.

There are two reference implementations of fdlibm 5.3 in the JDK:

- [s_modf.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/s_modf.c) (via bit twiddling)
- [e_modf.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/e_fmod.c) (via shift and subtract)