# Faster way to find modulus in java

Tags: java, modulo

I'm interested to find x % y where x is long and y is always 8.

I've the following implementation:

```
int result = (int) (x & 7);
```

I observed the performance (getting execution time for millions of operations with random inputs) of the above code over the traditional "%" operator and I didn't see any improvement.

'&' should runs faster than '%' - Right?

Comment: Most likely JIT eliminated your test code. Implementing microbenchmarks in Java is very tricky.

Comment: Not necessarily of duplicate of this, but likely highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367833/2055998.

Comment: Why do you think that "'&' should runs faster than '%' "  ?